# batch script stopped after ssh and did not continue

Tags: batch-file, ssh

This is my batch script. I wanted to automate restart of the mysql

```
cd G:\My Drive\TCL
G:
ssh -i themedcreations.pem ec2-user@ec2-3-16-127-158.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
sudo su
service mysqld restart
Pause
```

The script is okay if I manually input the lines in cmd.
I was hoping the batch file could run itself till the end, but it stops after running the ssh -i line, afterwards it requires manual input.

What went wrong? I am completely new to batch scripting. I tried timeout or wait. They all didn't work.

Comment: Are you expecting "sudo su" and the following commands to run on the remote system?

Comment: Yes. But the cmd prompt didn't run sudo su. they had to be manually typed in

Comment: There is no `sudo` command in Windows.  The cmd script runs on your host windows system, not the remote machine you connect to with ssh.

Answer (score -1):

Use the -n flag and see if it solves your problem.

example

```
ssh -n -i themedcreations.pem ec2-user@ec2-3-16-127-158.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```